# submenu is not positioning as desired

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make my dropdown menu like in the image below. The problem is when I hover on the second item of main menu, the submenu leaves a margin from top as shown on left hand side of picture. I do not want that empty space. I want the submenu to always show on the same size and position for all the main menu options which have a submenu.

[image: only the freehand red circle is missing]

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
   position:relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
   top:0;
   left:100%;
   margin-top:-6px;
   margin-left:0px;
   -webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
   -moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
   border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
 }

.dropdown-submenu > a:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  float: right;  
  height: 0;     
  margin-right: -1px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 190px;
  padding-left:10px;  
}
#abg > li > a:hover, #abg > .active > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;  
  background-color:#49b3e7;
  padding-top:15px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}  

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-nav  {
     display: inline;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    display: inline;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: red;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 2px;   
  }
   .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
     color: #333;
   }
   .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
   .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
     background-color: #ccc;
   }

   .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
     border-bottom: 1px solid white; 
     border-radius: 0;
   }
  .dropdown-menu {
      padding-left: 10px;
  }
  .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu {
      padding-left: 20px;
   }
   .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu {
      padding-left: 30px;
   }
   li.dropdown.open {
    border: 0px solid red;
   }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  ul.nav li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  #navbar {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div id="navbar">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top hidden-xs " role="navigation" style="background-color:#49b3e7;color:white;margin-top:50px;cursor:pointer">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown" style="cursor:pointer">
                        <a href="ab10.html"><span  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:white;cursor:pointer;">All Products </span><span class="caret" style="color:white;cursor:pointer;"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="abg">
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="ab10.html" style="cursor:pointer;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-4" id="firstdivtext"><span class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="cursor:pointer;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">Grocery</span></div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right " id="thirddivarrow"></span></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="abg" style="width:250px;height:500px;border:1px solid white;text-align: -webkit-match-parent;">
                                    <li><a href="ab2.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Meals & Prep</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab3.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Spreads & Sweeteners</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab4.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Breafast</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab5.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Salty Snacks</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab6.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Chocolate & Candy</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab7.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Condiments & Spices</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab8.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Fruits & Nuts</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab9.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Cookies & Bars</a></li>
                                    <hr>
                                    <li><a href="ab11.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Shop All Grocery</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull right" style="width:250px;height:500px;margin-left:240px;border:1px solid white;">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <h3 style="color:#49b3e7;margin-left:70px;margin-top:190px;"> Dole-licious </br>Snacks </h3>
                                        <img src="grocery1.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="ab10.html" style="cursor:pointer;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-4" id="firstdivtext"><span class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="cursor:pointer;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">Beverages</span></div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right " id="thirddivarrow"></span></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="abg" style="width:250px;height:500px;border:1px solid white;text-align: -webkit-match-parent;">
                                    <li><a href="ab12.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Coffee & Tea</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab13.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Dairy</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab14.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Jucies</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab15.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Mixes</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab16.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Sports & Energy</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab17.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Water & Sparkling</a></li>
                                    <hr>
                                    <li><a href="ab18.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Shop All Beverages</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull right" style="width:250px;height:500px;margin-left:240px;border:1px solid white;margin-top:-61px;">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <h3 style="color:#49b3e7;margin-left:77px;margin-top:163px;"> Flavorful</br> fun made </br>easy</h3>
                                        <img src="beverages1.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="ab10.html" style="cursor:pointer;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-4" id="firstdivtext"><span class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="cursor:pointer;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">Bath & Body</span></div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right " id="thirddivarrow"></span></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="abg" style="width:250px;height:500px;border:1px solid white;">
                                    <li><a href="ab19.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Deodorants</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab20.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Hand Soaps</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab21.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Shaving</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab22.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Shower</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab23.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Skin Care</a></li>
                                    <hr>
                                    <li><a href="ab24.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Shop All Bath & Body</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull right" style="width:250px;height:500px;margin-left:240px;border:1px solid white;margin-top:-116px;">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <h3 style="color:#49b3e7;margin-left:70px;margin-top:190px;"> Would you </br>Lather </h3>
                                        <img src="bath&body1.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="ab10.html" style="cursor:pointer;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-4" id="firstdivtext"><span class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="cursor:pointer;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">Health</span></div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right " id="thirddivarrow"></span></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="abg" style="width:250px;height:500px;border:1px solid white;">
                                    <li><a href="ab25.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Ladies</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab26.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Dental & Eye</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab27.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Relief</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab28.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Supplements</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab29.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Adult Care</a></li>
                                    <hr>
                                    <li><a href="ab30.html">Shop All Health</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull right" style="width:250px;height:500px;margin-left:240px;border:1px solid white;margin-top:-171px;">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <h3 style="color:#49b3e7;margin-left:70px;margin-top:190px;">Picture of </br>Health </h3>
                                        <img src="health.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="ab10.html" style="cursor:pointer;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-4" id="firstdivtext"><span class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="cursor:pointer;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">Cleaning Supplies</span></div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right " id="thirddivarrow"></span></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="abg" style="width:250px;height:500px;border:1px solid white;">
                                    <li><a href="ab31.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Surface Cleaners</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab32.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Paper & Plastic</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab33.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Laundry</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab34.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;"> Dish Soaps</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab35.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Air & Fresheners</a></li>
                                    <hr>
                                    <li><a href="ab36.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Shop All Cleaning Supplies</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull right" style="width:250px;height:500px;margin-left:240px;border:1px solid white;margin-top:-226px;">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <h3 style="color:#49b3e7;margin-left:70px;margin-top:190px;"> So Fresh </br>and Clean </h3>
                                        <img src="cleaning.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="ab10.html" style="cursor:pointer;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-4" id="firstdivtext"><span class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="cursor:pointer;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">Home & Office</span></div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right " id="thirddivarrow"></span></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="abg" style="width:250px;height:500px;border:1px solid white;">
                                    <li><a href="ab37.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Stationery</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab38.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Appliances & Tools</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab39.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Tabletop & Storage</a></li>
                                    <hr>
                                    <li><a href="ab40.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Shop All Home & Office</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull right" style="width:250px;height:500px;margin-left:240px;border:1px solid white;margin-top:-281px;">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <h3 style="color:#49b3e7;margin-left:70px;margin-top:190px;"> Lock in the </br>freshness </h3>
                                        <img src="home.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="ab10.html" style="cursor:pointer;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-4" id="firstdivtext"><span class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="cursor:pointer;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">Babies & Kids </span></div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right " id="thirddivarrow"></span></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="abg" style="width:250px;height:500px;border:1px solid white;">
                                    <li><a href="ab41.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Care & Cleaning</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab42.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Diapers & Wipes</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ab43.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Nutrition</a></li>
                                    <hr>
                                    <li><a href="ab44.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Shop All Babies & Kids</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull right" style="width:250px;height:500px;margin-left:240px;border:1px solid white;margin-top:-336px;">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <h3 style="color:#49b3e7;margin-left:70px;margin-top:190px;"> Baby got </br> Bath </h3>
                                        <img src="baby.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="ab45.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">Lifestyle<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="margin-left:150px;color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);"></span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="ab46.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;border-bottom:1px solid #6d6d6d;">Pets <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="margin-left:150px;color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);"></span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="ab47.html" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">Shop All Products <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="margin-left:100px;color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);"></span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="ab49.html" style="color:white;">Best Sellers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ab50.html" style="color:white;">What's New</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ab51.html" style="color:white;">On Sale</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ab52.html" style="color:white;">Samples</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: You mean you want the submenu to pop out from the top of the parent menu instead of where the user actually clicks? That seems like a terrible idea. Why would you want to break a basic GUI convention for your users?

Comment: sorry client requirement

Comment: you can place it in an absolute position from the navigation container with top: 0, left: 100%?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: static;
}
```

This places your submenu dropdowns relative to your main dropdown menu.

Comment: Then you are doing something else wrong, just tried it with your code, works great.. http://jsfiddle.net/okqyzked/

Comment: Why a downvote? It really solves the OP question. I tryed it on a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7whz6seh/

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `position: static` and `top: 0` in CSS.

```
.dropdown-submenu {
   position: static;
   top: 0;
   left: 100%;
}
```